# Session anti-affinity in Kubernetes

Tags: security, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am running an EKS cluster. And I have a use case which I will explain below.

So, I am trying to create a scalable CTF (Capture the Flag). Now, the problem is - there are a few challenges in which the participants have to write a few files within the pod. Now, obviously, I don't want, another participant to have the remote session when the first user was writing the files within the pod. If that happens, the second user will automatically get the solution.

In order to avoid this problem, we thought of implementing a solution like "session anti-affinity", i.e., if a pod has a session with one user, the ingress should send the request to another pod, but we are not able to understand how to implement the solution.

Please help us out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a software architecture question

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for session affinity solution using ingress, you need to enable proxy protocol first.  Which will have information of source ip.  In ingress you use the information to achieve affinity.

But the problem statement you had mentioned is kind of locking. at given point only one user has to serviced.  Not sure session affinity will help in solving the problem.